# Mover rama a commit anterior

Tags: git

Es posible mover mi rama a otro commit? La situacion que se me presenta es que en un proyecto hubo algunos cambios realizados por parte de un colaborador y empece a trabajar desde ese punto, pero el problema que tengo es que me recomiendan pasarme a algun commit anterior antes de los cambios de ese colaborador que hacen que el codigo falle, pero no tengo realmente idea de como hacerlo. Hasta el momento despues de buscar un rato solo he encontrado como mover un commit a otras ramas pero nada de mover una rama a otro commit, en este caso anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que estás en un *feature branch*, lo que tienes que hacer es un rebase.

Digamos que la situación es esta:

```
 * G Segundo commit de mi rama (mi-rama)
 * F Primer commit de mi rama
 * E Commit donde hay fallas (main)
 * D Un commit X
 * C Commit donde te estan pidiendo pararte
 * B Un commit X
 * A Un commit X
```

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
git rebase commit-malo-del-colaborador mi-rama --onto el-commit-que-te-recomiendan
```

Aplicado al diagrama que puse, sería

```
git rebase main mi-rama --onto C
```

Estoy usando `main` en vez del commit que quieres evitar ya que la rama está justo en el commit malo que ya forma parte de la historia de tu rama pero también podrías usar cualquier commit o rama que incluya el commit dañado en su historia.

Con eso tu rama va a quedar montada en el commit C, así:

```
 * G' Segundo commit de mi rama (mi-rama)
 * F' Primer commit de mi rama
 |  * E Commit donde hay fallas (main)
 |  * D Un commit X
 | /
 * C Commit donde te estan pidiendo pararte
 * B Un commit X
 * A Un commit X
```